# Parse Cloud Code Push + Client-initiated push isn't enabled

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

I am trying to run a parse cloud code function that sends a push to a user that is associated with an installation object. When I run the following code from within the cloud function I get Error 115 - Client-initiated push isn't enabled.

```
    // SEND PUSH TO PARENT
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    query.equalTo('user', reservation.get("parent"));
    Parse.Push.send({
        where: query, // Set our Installation query
        data: {
            alert: "Your request has been accepted!"
        }
    }, {
        success: function () {
            console.log("push worked");
            return result;

        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            return result;
        }
    });
```

I don't see anywhere that client side pushes need to be enabled for cloud code? Am I missing something or do I need it enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your app's settings in the Parse Dashboard, then enable client side push under Push Notifications.

[image: Screenshot]